# Generics return type E

Tags: java, generics

What is return type E in the following code

```
public E get(int index) {
  synchronized (mutex) {
    return super.get(index);
  }
}
```

[Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) says it's an Element. But i didn't get it correctly. It's helpful if i get explanation with an example.

Comment: I think it would probably really help to take a full-course tutorial on generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's whatever you say it is. If you have a `Mutex<Integer>` then it's an `Integer`. If you have a `Mutex<String>` then it's a `String`. If you have a `Mutex<Cheeseburger>` then it's a `Cheeseburger`. `E` is a special kind of *variable*, sort of like `int index` in your example. The difference is that `E` takes on types, not values.

Comment: E is not a variable, but its type

Comment: I've edited to clarify. I meant `E` is a type variable. I didn't mean to imply that `E` was a value-level construct.

Comment: So what's the difference between T and E?

Comment: @Nibras I really suggest you start from [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). Asking difference of `T` and `E` clearly shows that you have not read *any* tutorials on this topic. It takes a lot of effort to explain this when you are lacking the fundamental knowledge.